# Opencv3 - How to give ID to the people I count based on contours and rectrangles?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, tracking, counting

I want to give ID to the contourareas that I draw rectangle on them. Now my code tracks moving object on the screen and put a rectangle around them. I want to give an ID to the each of rectangles. I know how to count how many rectangles on the screen but I don't know how to give rectangles an exact ID that doesn't change when another rectangle joins the screen.

The code I use to draw rectangles:

```
video_path = 'C:\\Users\\MONSTER\\Desktop\\video.avi'
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)

version = cv2.__version__.split('.')[0]
print(version) 

#read video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

#check opencv version
if version == '2' :
    fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
if version == '3': 
    fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()


while (cap.isOpened):

    #if ret is true than no error with cap.isOpened
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret==True:

        #apply background substraction
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(fgmask,150,200,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)              
        #check opencv version
        if version == '2' : 
            (contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(th1.copy(), 
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        if version == '3' : 
        (im2, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(th1.copy(), 
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for c in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 200:
            continue

        #get bounding box from countour
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        #draw bounding box
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('foreground and background',th1)
    cv2.imshow('rgb',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I changed the code above to the code below to put text on rectangles but the text changes when another rectangle joins.

```
i = 1
        for c in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(c) < 200:
                continue

            #get bounding box from countour
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

            #draw bounding box
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            i = i + 1
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame,str(i),(x,y), font, 2,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Do you have any idea to give rectangles exact ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not do the tracking. only the detection from the background only. To make your code natively do the tracking, I am afraid it's not that simple. tracking will only happen if you have a perfect connected object and there is only 1 object. It usually rarely happens as fail detection happens all the time. Thus multiple RECT are created.

The ID will keep changes for different frames when you enter the scene and there are multiple detections like the image below. I tried it before. Each time the bounding rect will change from object to object. Especially when you use a simple method like bgfg, this lost track or lost id happens almost every frame.

The proper way is to use real tracking algorithm to constantly update the object. e.g

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvcyK4ZMKbM

[image]

The input to TLD tracker is from the Rect obtained by

```
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
```

The source code is in the github. feel free to test it

```
https://github.com/gnebehay/TLD
```

Follow the installation to get it up and integrate into your current detection routing.

```
https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD/wiki/Installation
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track multiple objects.

- You need to check their intersections and stop tracking when they collide.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/06/tracking-multiple-objects-with-opencv/